# How to add css class to local action menu item created with page manager variant 301 redirect?

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

I add some local action links with Page Manager using HTTP response code variant of type 301 redirect.
Anybody knows a way to add a unique class to such a link?

Comment: How 301 can create links?

Comment: It's a feature of *Page Manager* I am using. When you create a *page* with *PM* you can create a *variant*, and you can chose from *Panel*, *Panelizer* (if module is installed), and *HTTP response code*. If you chose the latter, you can chose *301 redirect* behavior (and the *redirect destination*). Assign your *page* a *menu item* of type *local action* and then you'll have a local action button redirecting you to the page path.